Why does retrieving the input fields not convert to int() type?
I started programming in python recently and I am making a game of chance in which the computer randomly chooses a number between 1 and 10 and the player must guess the number. I realized this by generating a window with Tkinter. However, by launching the program, no matter what value I come in, even letters, it tells me that the number is greater. The error is in response() but I can not solve it. If you can help me and also tell me if you see any other errors I thank you very much! Here is my script:
from tkinter import *
from random import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("400x400")
window.minsize(600, 500)
window.maxsize(600, 500)
window.title("Jeu de hasard")
window["bg"] = "grey"

def starting():
    text_1 = Label(window, text="Choisis un nombre entre 1 et 10.", font=("Verdana", 15, "italic bold"), bg="grey", fg="white")
    text_1.place(x=10, y=100)

def reponse():
    nb = randint(1, 10)
    player_reponse = champs_de_saisie.get()
    player_reponse = int()
    duration = 3000
    if player_reponse < nb:
        loose_text_1 = Label(window, text="Dommage, réessaie, le nombre est plus grand.", font=    ("Verdana", 15, "italic bold"), bg="grey", fg="white")
        loose_text_1.place(x=10, y=130)
        loose_text_1.after(duration, loose_text_1.destroy)
    if player_reponse > nb:
        loose_text_2 = Label(window, text="Dommage, réessaie, le nombre est plus petit.", font=("Verdana", 15, "italic bold"),bg="grey", fg="white")
        loose_text_2.place(x=10, y=130)
        loose_text_2.after(duration, loose_text_2.destroy)
    if player_reponse == nb:
        win_text = Label(window, text="Bravo, tu as gagné !", font=("Verdana", 15, "italic bold"),bg="grey", fg="white")
        win_text.place(x=10, y=130)
        win_text.after(duration, win_text.destroy)

champs_de_saisie = Entry(window,  bg="white", font="Arial 12", width=15)
champs_de_saisie.place(x=400, y=245)
champs_de_saisie.delete(0, END)

lbl = Label(window, text="Saisis ici :", font="Arial 12", bg="grey", fg="white")
lbl.place(x=430, y=215)

start_button = Button(window, text="Commencer", bg="blue", fg="white", font="Arial 15",     width=27, command=starting)
start_button.place(x=0, y=0)

valid_button = Button(window, text="Valider", bg="green", command=reponse)
valid_button.place(x=445, y=275)

leave_button = Button(window, text="Quitter", bg="red", fg="white", font="Arial 15", width=27,   command=window.destroy)
leave_button.place(x=300, y=0)

window.mainloop()


There is no def answer. Do you mean def response?

player_reponse = int() With no argument, int() returns 0. If you want to convert something to an integer, you need to put that something in the argument list.

If you want something that automatically converts an input field to integer, associate an IntVar with the input.

player_reponse = champs_de_saisie.get()
player_reponse = int()

Here you're setting player_response to a new int object, which gives you a 0.
You actually need to do this to cast an object to an int:
player_reponse = int(champs_de_saisie.get())

But ideally you'd validate that your data is actually a number first, otherwise you'll get an exception.

Thank you very much the program finally works but it is necessary to leave nb=randint of reponse() otherwise the computer does not leave the possibility to the player to try again and immediately rechoisi another number. Thanks for your help!

Yeah, I wasn't suggesting to remove that part, I was just referring to the two lines in my answer. Glad it works though, feel free to accept my answer!
